How to Capture multiple tabs of a pageview in a flutter using screenshot and save in an array?
I want to capture 3 pages in carousel_slider using screenshot package and save in an array.
but I am not able to capture the image.
Screenshot(
     controller: _screenshotController,
     child: CarouselSlider.builder(
         itemCount: 3,
         itemBuilder: (context, index, realIndex) {
                    return SingleWeddingPage();
}))

I just need to capture the images and then turn it to a PDF.
